# Difference in means test on pandas's summary statistics?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, statistical-test

I am looking to perform a difference in means test on the summary statistics of two DataFrames.

```
df1[['sd']].describe()
                sd
count  5000.000000
mean      0.635558
std       0.086109
min       0.492922
25%       0.577885
50%       0.639906
75%       0.688645
max       0.800767

df2[['sd']].describe()
                sd
count  5000.000000
mean      0.640954
std       0.084459
min       0.496823
25%       0.577373
50%       0.644122
75%       0.693863
max       0.798076
```

I am looking for some function I can call on these summary statistics to tell me if my difference in means is statistically significant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If You observe two independent samples from the same or different population then perform t-test for independent samples.

This is a two-sided test for the null hypothesis that two independent samples have equal average values.

```
from scipy.stats import ttest_ind

ttest_ind(df1['sd'], df2['sd'])
```

Output will be t-statistic and the p-value.